# how to show D3.js HTML graph in Github

Tags: github, d3.js, plot

I tried to let d3.js graph can show in github.But failed.Does it have any methods to solve this problem.

I had pushed d3 html graph into github.Because it didn't render,so I could not see the plot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) to turn your repository into a website.
Then the javascript will actually run.

Comment: You could also create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and use [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/)

Comment: How can I show preview of HTML in Gits? BTW,  `bl.ocks` now is [ObservableHQ](https://observablehq.com/)